# htaccess rewrite issues - continuing rewrite

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I'm experimenting with some rewrites on a domain. The htaccess is currently set up to take into account something after the forward slash. eg.
mysite.dev/page1/

I wish to change this to:
mysite.dev/page1.html

so I've put a forward on the original link and setup the new rewrite for the .html pages as follows:

```
Redirect 301 /page1/ http://mysite.dev/page1.html
Redirect 301 /page1 http://mysite.dev/page1.html
Redirect 301 /page2/ http://mysite.dev/page2.html
Redirect 301 /page2 http://mysite.dev/page2.html
Redirect 301 /page3/ http://mysite.dev/page3.html
Redirect 301 /page3 http://mysite.dev/page3.html

RewriteRule ^page1.html$ page.php?slug=page1 [L]
RewriteRule ^page2.html$ page.php?slug=page2 [L]
RewriteRule ^page3.html$ page.php?slug=page3 [L]

RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)/?$ page.php?slug=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)/([^/.]+)/?$ page.php?slug=$2 [L]
```

When going to mysite.dev/page1.html it works fine. But when putting mysite.dev/page1/ it will rewrite to mysite.dev/page1.html?slug=page1. So it seems to continue to follow the rest of the rules.

Any help/suggestions on a way around this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Avoid mixing mod_alias and mod_rewrite rule.

Also add this rule **just before first RewriteRule** to avoid looping:

```
## If the request is for a valid directory
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
## If the request is for a valid file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
## If the request is for a valid link
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l
## don't do anything
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
```

#### Complete .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /(page1|page2|page3)[/\s\?] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1.html [L,R=301]

## If the request is for a valid directory
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
## If the request is for a valid file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
## If the request is for a valid link
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l
## don't do anything
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteRule ^(page1|page2|page3)\.html$ page.php?slug=$1 [L,QSA,NC]

RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)/?$ page.php?slug=$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)/([^/.]+)/?$ page.php?slug=$2 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Thanks. It's still seems to do exactly the same though.

Comment: As I suggested translate all of your mod_alias rules to mod_rewrite ones that will be using regex to match exact URI.

Comment: I have edited answer to show your complete .htaccess code with mod_rewrite rules. Check it out.

Comment: Thanks. I was nearly there, came back and noticed you had updated post. Works a treat. Thank you.

Comment: You're welcome, glad that it worked out for you. I was on mobile earlier so couldn't edit the answer.